# Div boxes won't align next to each other

Tags: css, html

okay so my coding is 
( idk if you cn see it the code is just making a div ugh )
heres the picture of the code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1yW1.png

and no matter what code I put to align center, left, right anything... it doesn't go.
heres what it looks like :
see this is how it is, 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Hf6.png

to view yourself, go to my website wonder-wh0re.tk and click "links"

Comment: Try removing the `<rpe>` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `pre` element and it will work as expected.

[Current Problem with pre](http://jsfiddle.net/p9fuA/2/)

[Expected result without pre](http://jsfiddle.net/p9fuA/)

Comment: Well i only put <pre> because I thought it would help show the code on here. @sachin

Comment: Without `pre` its showing the correct result. So can you please put your code on `jsfiddle.net` and reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the picture of the code but okay hold on a sec.... jsfiddle.net/Mt4Mp there @sachin

Comment: Just remove the two `br` tags after the first div. check it out http://jsfiddle.net/Mt4Mp/1/